# Is this supposed to be here in the shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

We've been in a newly built house for 3 months, and our shower is already slow to drain. I pulled off the cover to potentially plunge/snake it out and saw this plug thing that only partially opens.

Was that left in by mistake? Or is it some kind of backflow-prevention thing?

[image]

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like it's not supposed to be there, but its impossible to tell from this alone.  Does the grate have a brand name or numbers of any kind?

Comment: I have never tried to use a snake on a shower drain. I thought that showers had a kind of trap that would not allow a snake through. I have never heard of a back-flow prevent valve being used in a shower. It could be that this device never really worked as intended and caused more trouble than it was worth. Maybe it was retrofitted? What happens if you gently pull on it with pliers? Will it come out? Another thought is that this is the center of a breakout plug inserted for pressure testing of the drains. If so, it was supposed to be removed following testing.

Comment: Call the plumber or contractor that built the house to solve your problem. They all have a warranty period in which to fix problems with a newly built house..

Comment: From the photo, it looks like a rubber drain stopper that fell into the drain. If it is rubber, I'd remove it using a hemostat or needle-nosed pliers. It likely fell in when it was being used to plug the drain while testing the base for leaks.